# Extrapolate an XSL sheet from an Excel file

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xslt

I am not sure if this is even possible but here it is. I know that it is possible to generate an Excel file from an XML and use XSL to format it. Is it possible to feed an Excel file through some C# code to extrapolate an XSL from it? What I want to do is create a template in Excel, extrapolate an XSL sheet which I would then use to parse some XML through my system and populate an Excel sheet with the XSL formatting. I know it sounds confusing, but before I waste any more time online, I wonder whether anyone knows if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmh, I don't know well the XML format of Excel, I'm more comfortable with the OpenDocument one, which is for OpenDocument sheet, .ods files (OpenOffice, LibreOffice...).
It's full XML so you could generate it from XML input for sure.
I use XSLT for generating XML from .ods or .ods from XML.
I think for Excel is the same as long as you could access to the XML content of an Excel file.